# Storing data of shiny into mySql

Tags: mysql, r, shiny, amazon-rds, shiny-server

I want to insert my output of app to my sql database, i have succesfully made connection between database and shiny app here is my code

```
     library(shiny)
     library(DBI)
    ui <- fluidPage(
    textInput("id", "Enter your ID:", "1"),
 tableOutput("tbl")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
     output$tbl <- renderTable({
   conn <- dbConnect(
     drv = RMySQL::MySQL(),
  dbname = "shiny_database",
  host = "r.cr7lk1jwjdht.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com",
  username = "kartik",
  password = "12345678")
on.exit(dbDisconnect(conn), add = TRUE)
    query <- paste0("INSERT INTO db(id2 , id ) VALUES ('13','43') ")
  # dbGetQuery(conn, query)

 # query <- paste0("SELECT * FROM db WHERE id = '", input$id, "';")   
dbGetQuery(conn, query)

 })
  }
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Here i can insert my data by using insert query but when i have huge output data to insert , in that case i cannot use insert query again and again.
Can anyone help me how i can insert my data.
After searching i also find that there is temp folder in which output is store temporary, if it is possible that i can use temp folder for putting data in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert dataframe into database like below basic code.

```
library(shiny)
library(DBI)
library(pool)
pool <- dbPool(drv = RMySQL::MySQL(),dbname = "db_name",host = "host",username = "user_name",password = "password", port = 3306)

ui <- fluidPage(
  submitButton("submit")
)
server <- function(input, output){
  dbWriteTable(pool, "dummyTable", df, append = TRUE) #this will insert the entire dataframe at once into dummyTable
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

To proceed with this method you need to frame all the values into a dataframe. When you submit the button the dataframe will be inserted into table. (Do not post user credetials unless they are duplicate)

Comment: Thanks for your support.But i have one doubt does here dummyTable  is the table that i have to create in my database which contains only attributes with suitable names and datatypes? and just to be sure df is the name of dataframe.

Comment: The above method works if there a table in database with the name `dummyTable` and you want to store your dataframe `df` into database. Both `df` and `dummyTable` should have same data types and fields.

Comment: Else if there is no table called `dummyTable` in your database, then it creates a table with that name and stores your dataframe `df` into database.

Comment: Thanks problem solved .If i want to change the attribute name in table keeping my dataframe unchanged, can i do that? in place of append=TRUE in dbWriteTable i will write overwrite = TRUE.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you suggest me method to retrieve the data from database , as i wanted to get my shiny app output fast @msr_003

Answer (score 0):

How about using actionButton() ?
https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.1/actionButton.html

You can place `actionButton(inputId = "IDForActionButton")` in ui.R.
The `actionButton()` creates a button on UI.
And when the button is pressed, that triggers re-calculation of server.R codes which include `input$IDForActionButton`.

You have to enclose the `input$id` with isolate() as shown in the link.
Because, without doing so, every time the content of input$id is changed, it triggers re-calculation of server.R codes which include `input$id`.

Probably using the pool library will help you.
https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/pool-basics.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply but in second case it is performing select query  manually but what i actually want is to perform insert query for large number of attributes which i cannot do by adding query manually, as soon as action button is pressed it should add all the data in database table. Correct me if i am wrong anywhere.